# What about Aptana 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, netbeans, aptana

I tried aptana few months ago where only the beta version was available.
Unfortunately, I had a lot of problems and for this reason I turn back on NetBeans. Today I noticed that the version 3.0.2 is available but I don't want to make the mistake again, before changing platform, I would like to know by some Aptana's users what they think. Is there valid reasons to change my currently IDE Netbeans passing to Aptana for RoR 3 developing ?
 **What are the features that Aptana offer and Netbeans doesn't has ?**

Comment: I used **Aptana Studio 3** for the past 4 months and I really like this IDE. Please note that I'm using **Windows 7** and Aptana's build-in console is just **perfect** !

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you will want to use RubyMine. It's by far the most complete Rails IDE and you can really customize it to work the way you want. There is a trial version for 30 days on their site. I am currently using it in conjunction with the VIM bundle and loving it. Netbeans is not supported anymore so you will probably want to move out at one point.

Comment: RubyMine ... never tried, I'll do it tanks for the suggestion, can you tell me if you think it's better than Aptana ?

Comment: I tried Aptana once and it was very slow (like driving a tank). The other problem is that it's not up to pace with th evolution of rails (which as you now changes often). For my workflow I work in RubyMine when working on a lot of files in a project or in VIM if I work simply on a few files (faster). The best of both worlds